# Fixed vertical scrollable column

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

How can I make the `table` at http://portal.blackbox-tracking.com/reports/table.html vertically scroll-able while maintaining the horizontal scroll and the "blue" border? Also, I want to make the `<thead>` "fixed". (gave a like since it's too much code to post directly)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at fiddle for fixed header and scroll on body. Hope This satisfies the task.. Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/8/

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped mainhelloo">
    <thead class="waah">
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="helloo">
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
.mainhelloo thead, tbody, tr, td, th {
     display: block; 
}
.mainhelloo tr:after {
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            visibility: hidden;
            clear: both;
        }


        .helloo {
            height: 120px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .waah{
            width: 100%;
        }


        .mainhelloo td, .mainhelloo th {
            width: 25%;
            float: left;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found CSS-only solutions to this problem are not supported in older browsers that you still usually need to support (IE7, IE8). The following jQuery plugin has allowed me to create complex scrollable tables with fixed headers, sorting, etc. for a few successful commercial projects:

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html

You can still style the table however you wish, including borders. If you want a blue border containing the entire table (header, body and all) then I recommend placing the table inside a container DIV and styling that DIV to have the border you want while removing an outer border from the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/2wuL8/)** , made few changes in `#timeline` CSS properties.